# thmtools: Parentheses behaving weirdly in note

Tags: thmtools

I used `thmtools` package to define theorem style because I wanted just the note to have a different colour:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} 

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove = \topsep,
spacebelow = \topsep,
headfont = \normalfont\bfseries,
notefont = \color{olive}\normalfont\mdseries,
notebraces = {}{},
headformat = \NAME{} {\NUMBER}\NOTE,
headpunct = {\newline},
bodyfont = \normalfont\upshape
]{fordefinition}

\theoremstyle{fordefinition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\begin{defn}[Property(T) group]
asdg
\end{defn}
\end{document}
```

But parentheses `()` behave weirdly within the note. The right parenthesis always appears at the end of the note.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this so that I get the parenthesis where I want it to?
I tried using `\right)` but it didn't work and I don't think it is a good idea.

P.S. Have I also defined the newline properly to give a line break after the heading? It works, but I am unsure whether this is the ideal way to do it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please expand your code to form a complete minimal working example (MWE)?

Comment: I have updated the question. This should compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's strange, indeed. I tried a few things, well known candidates for trouble, amongst which:

- putting a `%` at line ends is needed in macros, but irrelevant here
- treating the parantheses as a unit (so to say) was vital: `{(T)}`

Looks like otherwise you confuse this package when its internals "eat and digest" the data (as Knuth put it for TeX) :

- ...
- processing `t` is fine
- processing `y` is fine
- processing   is fine
- processing `(` puts you on the wrong route

That's it.

[image: result]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687217/thmtools-parentheses-behaving-weirdly-in-note

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} 

\declaretheoremstyle[%
spaceabove = \topsep,%
spacebelow = \topsep,%
headfont = \normalfont\bfseries,%
notefont = \color{olive}\normalfont\mdseries,%
notebraces = {}{},%
headformat = \NAME{} {\NUMBER}\NOTE,%
headpunct = {\newline},%
bodyfont = \normalfont\upshape%
]{fordefinition}

\theoremstyle{fordefinition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
 \begin{defn}[Property {(T)} group]% <<<
    Some of the most wonderful theorems ever heard of.
 \end{defn}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Treating the parantheses as a unit worked.

Comment: This is indeed the solution. The source of the problem is with the internal macro `\thmt@embrace`, which is defined as `\def\thmt@embrace#1#2(#3){#1#3#2}`.

Answer (score 1):

The `thmtools` package uses `()` in order to delimit the note in some of its macros (it shouldn't) and this fails if there are parentheses in the notes.

Here I patch the relevant commands to use `<>` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thmt@setheadstyle}{(}{<}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\thmt@setheadstyle}{)}{>}{}{}
\def\thmt@embrace#1#2<#3>{#1#3#2}
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove = \topsep,
  spacebelow = \topsep,
  headfont = \normalfont\bfseries,
  notefont = \color{olive}\normalfont\mdseries,
  notebraces = {}{},
  headformat = \NAME\ \NUMBER\NOTE,
  headpunct = {\newline},
  bodyfont = \normalfont\upshape
]{fordefinition}

\theoremstyle{fordefinition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{defn}[Property(T) group]
asdg
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

[image]